# Why are inheritance and interfaces restricted to instance members?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, inheritance, instance, static

Disclaimer: I think the rules are almost the same in most OO languages, but since I'm most familiar with C# I'll be relating to this specific language.

I think that the use of attributes and reflection could be largely reduced if static members would apply the same principles as OO instances.

Static properties and methods can be "overridden" by decedents by using the new keyword, but they cannot be forced to implement one via an interface, neither can the 'base' keyword be used (only explicitly naming the base type is supported). To make things worse, the members cannot be referenced via an instance, but have to always be specifically qualified with the exact type.

Constructors also have limited "inheritance" support, one can choose which base constructor is called, but you cannot force an object to support a constructor that takes certain parameters by defining it in an interface.

The best hint I could find to answer this question so far is [this one on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002376/659778) (answering a different question).

In his answer Jörg points out three principals that apply to Object Orientation:

- messaging,
- local retention and protection and hiding of state-process, and
- extreme late-binding of all things.

Now I fully understand that if you want to pass on a state-full class from one method to another as an object, these principles make sense. However in my opinion the principle of inheritance, overriding base methods with alternative or additional functionality, could also be beneficial to stateless business logic.

One example where forcing an object to implement a certain constructor would be helpful is with de-serialization. For example where the constructor should accept an XML node. In C# it is dynamically implementable using reflection, but having compile-time errors and avoiding the reflection boilerplate would add lots of value!

Static method/member interfaces would be helpful in situations where some aspects of a value are type specific, without any relation to the instance. For example a class could have a DisplayName, Unit, Weight, Factor or other aspects that are the same across all instances of the specific type, regardless of the instance value. Attributes (or Annotation) can be used to exploit these without the need to create an instance, however, there again it's extra boilerplate code and no way to enforce their implementation with compile-time errors.

I admit there are many simple ways to work around these points, I'm not looking for workarounds. Returning a static value in an instance-property is quite common, and it is not that much overhead to create an instance of an object just to read out the type-specific aspects, but I'd like to know the rationale background on why static things have been systematically excluded. I have heard about "the virtual stack" before, but don't really know how it works technically (and cannot find any simple explanation on the net).

Are the reasons of technical or philosophical nature?

---

Edit: elaborating on static interfaces:

An example of how I think a static interface could provide a strongly typed, compiletime checked, alternative to reflection:

```
public staticInterface MyStaticInterface
{
    constructor(XmlNode node);
    string DisplayName { get; }
    int Weight { get; }
}
```

The usage:

```
public void FillNodesToolBox() 
{
    MyStaticInterface[] nodes = 
        assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Implements<MyStaticInterface>());

    for (int i = nodes.Length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(
            nodes[i].DisplayName, " (", nodes[i].Weight.ToString(), ")"));
    }
}
```

Looking back, this actually looks like making my Type object inherit from System.Type, adding some properties to it, which is different than a static member...

`string.Empty != typeof(string).Emty` (the latter will not compile).

Maybe I'm starting to find the answer, but it feels like I'm walking in a paradoxical circle, it doesn't quite 'snap' yet....

Comment: In Scala, instead of static methods and fields within classes, you create `objects` which are singletons that otherwise behave like normal classes and allow inheritance, interfaces, etc. which is IMHO a much more object-oriented approach than static members.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski Yes, one could force an object to implement a property that returns a singleton with meta-data (well you could not force it to be a singleton, but by convention it would). However you would still need an instance of that object to get to that metadata. Attributes (annotation) work better, but cannot be enforced compile-time. To be honest, I'm not really looking for a workaround (invented many already), rather for the reasoning how this all came about to what it is today.

Answer (score 2):

It simply cannot work.

Lets say you have class A that defines a "virtual" static method. Then you have classes B and C that derive from A and both override this static method. Then you call A.StaticMethod(). Which of the B or C should be called?

The reason why virtual methods are tied to instance is because the type of the instance specifies which implementation of the virtual method is called. If you don't have this information, then you can't call the proper method.

Also, if you try to argue that you have to call the static method on a type it is implemented in (eg. B.StaticMethod() or C.StaticMethod()), then that is not virtual method call and can already be implemented in C# without problems.

> Now I fully understand that if you want to pass on a state-full class from one method to another as an object, these principles make sense. However in my opinion the principle of inheritance, overriding base methods with alternative or additional functionality, could also be beneficial to stateless business logic.

The business logic might seem stateless from abstraction's viewpoint. So you design your interfaces or abstract classes around that. But then, you realize you want to parametrize specific behavior at runtime. With instance virtual methods this is easy. Just create new subtype that contains state specifies this parametrization. Nothing stops you from having stateless instances with just methods, but having ability to add state without changing the abstraction is huge advantage of OOP. By having the methods static, you are removing this advantage.

If you really think that "stateless" programming is better for your project, it might be good idea to look at functional programming, which is all about composing methods with minimal state keeping.

Comment: Ok, that's a clear answer to why the inheritance part would not make sense, so you've answered half of the question. The other half is about interfaces. I know about functional programming, but for the time being I'm holding onto my trusty statefull encapsulated objects. I was thinking about a complie-time alternative to runtime reflection. I guess I'll edit my question to elaborate.

Comment: @LouisSomers With interfaces, what stops you from using a normal interface, instantiating the object and then calling it? While your idea might seem interesting, it doesn't add anything new so effort needed to implement such feature is not worth it.

Comment: With simple little objects that's easy, but with heavier stuff that use resources it's a bit more difficult. Some objects lack default constructors or need quite a bit of mocking in order to get an instance. I have abused FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject in the past to get around some resource hogs, and I have also used attributes allot. Any way, I was just wondering if the issues are more technical than conceptual of nature. I don't have the illusion that Microsoft will change C# after reading this :-) I just like to know the background and reasons for the choices made.

Comment: I can't think what abstract static methods could be useful for, but virtual static methods (if allowed) could be useful with generics.  If `A` defines `virtual static int foo()`, overridden by `B` and `C`, and shadowed by `D`, then `A.foo()` will refer to A's method, always, but given generic type `T` constrained to `A`, `T.foo()` would refer to `B.foo` when `T` is `B`, `C.foo` when `T` is `C`, and `A.foo` when `T` is `A` or `D`.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons why an interface can't dictate a constructor signature or the presence of static methods are primarily technical.

When calling method `I::foo` of interface `I`, the runtime environment needs a bit of metadata to know if it is actually `X::foo` or `Y::foo` that should be invoked. This metadata is specific for the object on which the method is invoked and thus attached to that object.

The problem with constructors and static methods is that they are invoked when there is no object available (yet). This means that there is no metadata available for the runtime environment to determine from which class to invoke the constructor or static method.

Comment: Ok, but if we do have an instance of System.Type to pass on then there should be enough info. I guess that System.Type is quite .Net specific, however I do remember having RTTI before .Net dominated my career. I'm guessing that the reason for not supporting static stuff in interfaces might have to do with keeping things in sync with legacy?

Answer (score 1):

The conceptual reason interfaces can't declare "abstract static members" is that the purpose of an interface is to specify what can be done with an *object*, not with a *type*. For example, the .NET interface `IList<T>` is a type representing objects which behave as lists.

Now, it *does* make sense to specify a list of operations which can be performed on a type rather than an object. But such a thing is called a *typeclass*, not an interface.

### Typeclasses

If C# supported typeclasses, then a typeclass declaration might look something like this:

```
typeclass CMonoidalList<T> of TList : IList<T>
{
    TList(IEnumerable<T> contents); // a constructor
    TList Append(TList suffix); // an instance method
}
```

A class implementing this typeclass could look like this:

```
class MyIntList : CMonoidalList<int>
{
    public MyIntList(IEnumerable<int> contents) { ... }
    public MyIntList Append(MyIntList suffix) { ... }
    ...
}
```

And a method which uses this typeclass would then look like this:

```
public static TList AppendString<TList>(TList list, string suffix)
    where TList : CMonoidalList<char>
{
    TList suffixList = new TList(suffix);
    return list.Append(suffixList);
}
```

### The problem with typeclasses

The downside of typeclasses, as compared to interfaces, is that typeclasses don't make sense as types the way that interfaces do. It does **not** make sense to write code which treats `CMonoidalList` as a type:

```
public static CMonoidalList<T> AppendBackwards<T>(
        CMonoidalList<T> suffix, CMonoidalList<T> prefix)
{
    return prefix.Append(suffix);
}
```

This code doesn't make sense because `Append` requires both `prefix` and `suffix` to be the *same* type implementing `CMonoidalList<T>`, but the argument list of `AppendBackwards` fails to express this.

This means that typeclasses are less convenient to use than interfaces, because you need to use `where` everywhere. And besides, interfaces are an important concept in object-oriented programming, whereas typeclasses are not.

### Interfaces can be better than typeclasses

Every typeclass you can think of *does* have a corresponding interface. The interface corresponding to your `MyStaticInterface` would be:

```
public interface MyClassyInterface<T>
{
    T New(XmlNode node);
    string DisplayName { get; }
    int Weight { get; }
}
```

This interface actually has an advantage over your typeclass: you can have multiple "implementations" of it for one single "implementing type" `T`. Sometimes you might want to have lots of different `DisplayNames` and `Weights` without having to write a separate class for each one. When you do, having an interface instead of a typeclass will come in handy.

One downside to this is that now you have to actually pass around implementations of the interface, instead of just obtaining them automatically from the implementing type. Another downside is the fact that you can have multiple "implementations" for one single "implementing type"—maybe you want to restrict things to one implementation per type!

### Other languages

Most languages don't have typeclasses, presumably because they're considered to be costly to implement (since, in general, *most* features are costly to implement) and wouldn't provide all that much benefit.

Haskell has full-fledged typeclasses, along with all of their advantages and disadvantages. Haskell programmers use typeclasses a lot and generally don't consider the disadvantages to be a very big deal.

Scala does not have typeclasses, but it has features to let you "fake it". If you want to write a "typeclass" in Scala, you convert it into an interface (as I described above) and write *that*. When you want to have an "implementation of the typeclass", you write an implementation of the interface and then declare that implementation as "implicit". Then you won't have to *explicitly* pass around implementations of the interface; the Scala compiler will try to make that happen completely automatically. It *usually* works.

Answer (score 0):

> Constructors also have limited "inheritance" support, one can choose which base constructor is called, but you cannot force an object to support a constructor that takes certain parameters by defining it in an interface.

An interface by definition has no knowledge of its underlying type. Technically there doesn't even need to be an underlying type; an interface is simply a collection of functions. Although mainstream OOP languages have a built-in mechanism for interfaces and expect you to "attach" them to classes, you could just as well take a bunch of delegates/lambdas/functions with known signatures into some container type and that'd be an interface too.

> One example where forcing an object to implement a certain constructor would be helpful is with de-serialization. For example where the constructor should accept an XML node.

In my opinion this is a bad idea. What happens when you want to serialize/deserialize the class in a different way? Or multiple ways at once? A class should have only one reason to change, and knowing how to serialize itself gives it a second reason. Granted, serialization is an interesting case because it requires breaking encapsulation, but I still feel it's best handled externally.

> Static method/member interfaces would be helpful in situations where some aspects of a value are type specific, without any relation to the instance. For example a class could have a DisplayName, Unit, Weight, Factor or other aspects that are the same across all instances of the specific type, regardless of the instance value.

A static field points to precisely one thing by definition; that's why it's not tied to any one instance of a class. Something can't be static and overridable at the same time. Think about what overriding something means; you'd have *something* that knows how to locate the field you're trying to access. That would make whatever you're trying to get an instance field. It might not be an instance field of the instances of the class, but you'd be turning the class itself into an object.

As a final note, inheritance is already a problematic mechanism. It's not inherently composable since you can only inherit from one thing at a time (otherwise you open up a different can of worms) and if you don't put restrictions on what can be overridden, changes to the base class that would be safe when considered in isolation can break subclasses. Being able to override static fields would be of *very* dubious value.

Comment: I think you miss the point on static members, it's not about properties or fields, but rather methods.  Methods that do what is desired, and don't require any state info.  If you want such a method to be used in an interface you have to (uselessly) make it an instance method.  And then to call it statically you have to create a second method, and name it something else.

Comment: @jmoreno Why would you want to put it in an interface in the first place?

Comment: Because it meets the requirements/signature.  A complication of course is that sometimes it only meets the VISIBLE signature, but other times it meets the actual signature.  Either way, why should it be excluded simply because it is static?

Comment: @jmoreno It doesn't meet the signature at all. The `object.function(arg)` is just an alternative notation for `function(object, arg)`. From there it's not hard to see that if `IFoo` requires method `frobnicate(Bar bar)`, it actually requires `frobnicate(IFoo ifoo, Bar bar)`. So your static `ConcreteFoo.frobnicate(Bar bar)` isn't a match. Besides that, a static method isn't part of a class. It's only there because of certain language's misguided notion that everything should be in an object. In any other language it'd be a free function. (continued...)

Comment: @jmoreno ...finally, an interface is just a bundle of functions. If you wanted to have access to a function with a certain signature but don't want to commit to one in particular, what you want is to be able to pass functions around directly instead of having them be treated as second-class citizens that you have to wrap into some anonymous object.

Comment: Re the signature -- that's what I meant by the VISIBLE signature, so I am aware of the difference. As for interface vs function pointers, depends on the need.

Comment: @jmoreno You could always just delegate all the implementation to the static function when implementing the interface.

Comment: Not sure if I'm fully following all you guys are saying, but the remark that `object.function(arg)` is just an alternative notation for `function(object, arg)` is quite enlightening. So the System.Type (or RTTI) is bound to that instance somehow. For static stuff the compiler would dismiss the Type on which a static method was implemented and just do a jump to the compiled address providing the arguments `function(arg)`? That would kind of explain things (if my assumptions are true).

Comment: @LouisSomers I'm not well versed in the implementation details, but yes, "static" means it has a fixed location that's known at compile time. Regarding the alternative notation, you might also find [this paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) interesting. It talks about the two main mechanisms for achieving abstraction and the differences between them. The tl;dr is that you can go with an abstract data type and hide the details of a type, or you can go with an object. In mainstream OOP languages the type whose details are hidden just happens to always be a record/struct.

Comment: If one has ten classes that need deserialization, having each class be responsible for deserialization may give it "another" reason to change, but if another class is responsible for deserialization, that class will have at least *ten* reasons to change.  There are ways in .NET a compiler could simulate virtual static methods (e.g. have such definitions create a nested class, and have the outer class create a singleton static instance); accessing such a thing the first time would require Reflection, but a generic static class could be used to cache the singletons associated with classes.

Comment: @supercat If you're serializing all your objects the same way, you don't have 10 reasons to change, because there's only one way to get the job done. If there's more than one serialization method, you'd put them each in separate classes, so each one only has one reason to change too.

Comment: @Doval: If there are NC classes and NS ways of serializing, then there's a potential need for NC * NS methods.  If all classes can work with some canonical method of deserialization (e.g. because no class contains anything but a bunch of separately-deserializable fields) one may have a deserialization library use NS methods to handle all classes, but if deserialization requires some class-specific work, that may be better handled within the separate classes.  If there exists a representation which is usable for everything (even if not wonderfully efficient)...

Comment: ...one could always have each class define a method to deserialize that as a minimum, and then have a deserialization library say that if no better means of deserialization is known, it can convert data to the universal format and use the known-to-be-available deserializer on that.

Comment: @supercat That's true. Even then, wouldn't it be a better separation of concerns to have each class produce a *representation* of its data rather than serialize/deserialize itself directly? Something like a Map<String, Object> or a more specific struct that could be used by something else to do the real work. Or is that what you meant by a canonical method of deserialization?

Comment: By "canonical method of deserialization", I meant doing something like using Reflection to load all class fields with values stored in the serialized data stream.  For some kinds of simple classes, Reflection can tell a deserialization method everything it needs to know.  In general, though, that won't suffice; constructing a legitimate instance of a type will generally require knowledge of its internals.  Having types define a factory method which builds a new instance according to data in a string is a little clunky, but will allow any instance of such a type to be serialized...

Comment: ...to any desired medium if the instance can supply a string from which the factory method can produce an equivalent instance.  Nothing else needs to know or care what the string "means", beyond the question of whether it can be guaranteed not contain certain characters [e.g. greater-than signs, ampersands, etc.].